# What is the best way to store list/vector of dynamically created objects?

Tags: c++, dynamic, storage

I was always wondering about this and today I have finally came to a moment that I need to get the answer right.

Namely: I am confused how should I store a list/vector/? of dynamically created objects ?

For instance: I have this program which will read from file, data about connections and then on this basis create `node`s (with connection information inside it) objects.

So the problem is: should I use `std::vector<node>` and in a `for` loop create temporary objects and `push_back()` them or use `std::vector<node*>` and `push_back()` pointers of dynamically allocated `node`s and then in the end of the program delete them ?

I do have the number of the elements which I would like to store.

Or maybe there is a better way of doing this and I am not aware about it.

Comment: Are these nodes polymorphic? (i.e. base classes with virtual functions et al)

Comment: ((Is it possible to calculate the number of objects by the size of the file?)) OK, nevermind, I just read that you have the number.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes They are not polymorphic (but if you reply please include a note on this as well) and I do know the number of elements to store.

Comment: If you don't need polymorphism (or have otherwise good reasons to use pointers), store the values directly in the vector.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oh, if you have a known size... allocate your vector with that known size (to eliminate the overhead of a resize during load), then the load is as efficient as a `memcpy()`. It'll just stack your values as expected. Highly efficient, more so than a pointer indirection.

If your elements are polymorphic, you'll need pointers. If you're concerned about cleaning up memory (you should be), consider using: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/libs/ptr_container/doc/ptr_vector.html

**[EDIT]**

If everything is constant sized, also consider http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/doc/html/array.html. It's like a C array, but without any resize overhead and STL support... if you really need speed.

Answer (score 2):

If you do not absolutely require dynamic allocation, do not use it.

Comment: The vector itself is dynamic allocation. Do you mean avoided manually allocating the `node` objects via `new node`?

Answer (score 2):

You would use `std::vector<node>` in that scenario.

You know the types, sizes, and element counts of what you need in advance. What you describe is perfect for vector -- you're dealing with a contiguous allocation.

In general, use of `std::list` should be very rare; vector is usually the right choice.

Also note that you can use `reserve()` to set the allocation size prior to population when you know the size -- this could save a lot of reallocation and node copying.